# Unable to resolve Unmet build dependencies

Tags: ati, dependencies, fglrx

I'm trying to install AMD driver for my graphic card Firepro V7900
this the installation log:

```
Generating package: Ubuntu/precise
Resolving build dependencies...
Unable to resolve  Unmet build dependencies.  Please manually install and try again.
Package build failed!
Package build utility output:
./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: 295: ./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: debclean: not found
dpkg-buildpackage: source package fglrx-installer
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 2:15.201-0ubuntu1
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution precise
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by AMD: Advanced Micro Devices. ati.amd.com/support/driver.html
 dpkg-source --before-build fglrx.eRBTh1
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
 debian/rules build
#Create important strings
for i in 10fglrx \
         control \
         dkms.conf \
         fglrx"".install \
         fglrx""-dev.install \
         fglrx""-dev.links \
         fglrx"".dirs \
         fglrx"".links \
         fglrx"".postinst \
         fglrx"".postrm \
         fglrx"".preinst \
         fglrx"".prerm \
         fglrx-amdcccle"".install \
         fglrx-amdcccle"".dirs \
         fglrx""-core.install \
         fglrx""-core.links \
         fglrx""-core.dirs \
         fglrx""-core.postinst \
         fglrx""-core.postrm \
         fglrx""-core.preinst \
         fglrx""-core.prerm \
         overrides/fglrx"" \
         overrides/fglrx""-dev \
         overrides/fglrx""-core \
         overrides/fglrx-amdcccle""; do \
    sed -e "s|#PKGXMODDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/xorg/modules|g" \
        -e "s|#LIBDIR#|usr/lib|g" \
        -e "s|#LIBDIR32#|usr/lib32|g" \
        -e "s|#BINDIR#|usr/bin|g" \
        -e "s|#SBINDIR#|usr/sbin|g" \
        -e "s|#SYSCONFDIR#|etc|g" \
        -e "s|#MANDIR#|usr/share/man/man1|g" \
        -e "s|#LDSOCONF#|usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf|g" \
        -e "s|#ALTLDSOCONF#|usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf|g" \
        -e "s|#ALTPRIORITY#|1000|g" \
        -e "s|#PXALTPRIORITY#|900|g" \
        -e "s|#AUTOSTARTDIR#|etc/xdg/autostart|g" \
        -e "s|#DATADIR#|usr/share|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGDESKDIR#|usr/share/fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGDATADIR#|usr/share/fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGCONFIGDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGBINDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/bin|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGLIBDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGLIBDIR32#|usr/lib32/fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGDRIVERSDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/xorg|g" \
        -e "s|#XORGEXTRA#|usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGEXTENSIONDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/xorg|g" \
        -e "s|#XORGEXTENSIONSDIR#|usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions|g" \
        -e "s|#DRIVERNAME#|fglrx""|g" \
        -e "s|#MODULENAME#|fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#DRIVERDIRNAME#|fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#DRIVERDEVNAME#|fglrx""-dev|g" \
        -e "s|#DRIVERSRCNAME#|fglrx-installer|g" \
        -e "s|#DRIVERCORENAME#|fglrx""-core|g" \
        -e "s|#FLAVOUR#|""|g" \
        -e "s|#DRIVERCTRLNAME#|fglrx-amdcccle""|g" \
        -e "s|#INCLUDEDIR#|usr/include|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGLIBCONFDIR#|lib/fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGXMODDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/xorg/modules|g" \
        -e "s|#PXDIR#|usr/lib/pxpress|g" \
        -e "s|#PXDIR32#|usr/lib32/pxpress|g" \
        -e "s|#PXXMODDIR#|usr/lib/pxpress/xorg/modules|g" \
        -e "s|#PXDIRNAME#|pxpress|g" \
        -e "s|#PXLIBDIR#|usr/lib/pxpress/lib|g" \
        -e "s|#PXLIBDIR32#|usr/lib32/pxpress/lib|g" \
        -e "s|#PXLDSOCONF#|usr/lib/pxpress/ld.so.conf|g" \
        -e "s|#ALTPXLDSOCONF#|usr/lib/pxpress/alt_ld.so.conf|g" \
        -e "s|#COREDIRNAME#|fglrx-core|g" \
        -e "s|#COREDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx-core|g" \
        -e "s|#COREDIR32#|usr/lib32/fglrx-core|g" \
        -e "s|#CORELDSOCONF#|usr/lib/fglrx-core/ld.so.conf|g" \
        -e "s|#COREPRIORITY#|1000|g" \
        -e "s|#UNBLKCOREPRIORITY#|900|g" \
        -e "s|#UNBLKCORELDSOCONF#|usr/lib/fglrx-core/unblacklist_ld.so.conf|g" \
        -e "s|#CVERSION#|15.201|g" \
        -e "s|#SRCXARCH#|xpic_64a|g" \
        -e "s|#SRCARCH#|x86_64|g" \
        -e "s|#SRCOTHERARCH#|x86|g" \
        -e "s|#SRCLIBDIR#|lib64|g" \
        -e "s|#DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH#|x86_64-linux-gnu|g" \
        -e "s|#OTHER_ARCH#|i386-linux-gnu|g" \
        debian/$i.in > debian/$i;      \
done
sed: can't read debian/fglrx-amdcccle.dirs.in: No such file or directory
# remove exec bit on everything
find arch \
    etc \
    lib \
    module \
    usr \
    xpic_64a     -type f | xargs chmod -x
find: 'module': No such file or directory
# set executable on user apps
find arch/x86_64/usr/sbin \
    arch/x86_64/usr/X11R6/bin \
    usr/sbin/ -type f | xargs chmod a+x
# set exec bit on scripts
find lib etc debian -name "*.sh" -type f | xargs chmod +x
# set the permissions on the pxpress scripts
chmod 744 debian/pxpress/switch*
dh build
make: dh: Command not found
debian/rules:241: recipe for target 'build-arch' failed
make: *** [build-arch] Error 127
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: 295: ./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: debclean: not found
dpkg-buildpackage: source package fglrx-installer
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 2:15.201-0ubuntu1
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution natty
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by AMD: Advanced Micro Devices. <http://ati.amd.com/support/driver.html>
 dpkg-source --before-build fglrx.s4OUPI
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
 debian/rules build
#Create important strings
for i in 10fglrx \
         dkms.conf \
         fglrx.install \
         fglrx-dev.install \
         fglrx-dev.links \
         fglrx-amdcccle.install \
         fglrx.grub-gfxpayload \
         fglrx.dirs \
         fglrx.links \
         fglrx.postinst \
         fglrx.postrm \
         fglrx.preinst \
         fglrx.prerm \
         overrides/fglrx; do \
    sed -e "s|#PKGXMODDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/xorg/modules|g" \
        -e "s|#LIBDIR#|usr/lib|g" \
        -e "s|#LIBDIR32#|usr/lib32|g" \
        -e "s|#BINDIR#|usr/bin|g" \
        -e "s|#SYSCONFDIR#|etc|g" \
        -e "s|#MANDIR#|usr/share/man/man1|g" \
        -e "s|#LDSOCONF#|usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf|g" \
        -e "s|#ALTPRIORITY#|1000|g" \
        -e "s|#PXALTPRIORITY#|900|g" \
        -e "s|#AUTOSTARTDIR#|etc/xdg/autostart|g" \
        -e "s|#DATADIR#|usr/share|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGDESKDIR#|usr/share/fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGDATADIR#|usr/share/fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGCONFIGDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGBINDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/bin|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGLIBDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGLIBDIR32#|usr/lib32/fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGDRIVERSDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/xorg|g" \
        -e "s|#XORGEXTRA#|usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGEXTENSIONDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/xorg|g" \
        -e "s|#XORGEXTENSIONSDIR#|usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions|g" \
        -e "s|#DRIVERNAME#|fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#DRIVERDEVNAME#|fglrx-dev|g" \
        -e "s|#DRIVERSRCNAME#||g" \
        -e "s|#INCLUDEDIR#|usr/include|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGLIBCONFDIR#|lib/fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#GRUBBLKLISTDIR#|usr/share/grub-gfxpayload-lists/blacklist|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGXMODDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/xorg/modules|g" \
        -e "s|#PXDIR#|usr/lib/pxpress|g" \
        -e "s|#PXDIR32#|usr/lib32/pxpress|g" \
        -e "s|#PXXMODDIR#|usr/lib/pxpress/xorg/modules|g" \
        -e "s|#PXDIRNAME#|pxpress|g" \
        -e "s|#PXLIBDIR#|usr/lib/pxpress/lib|g" \
        -e "s|#PXLIBDIR32#|usr/lib32/pxpress/lib|g" \
        -e "s|#PXLDSOCONF#|usr/lib/pxpress/ld.so.conf|g" \
        -e "s|#CVERSION#|15.201|g" \
        -e "s|#SRCXARCH#|xpic_64a|g" \
        -e "s|#SRCARCH#|x86_64|g" \
        -e "s|#SRCLIBDIR#|lib64|g" \
        debian/$i.in > debian/$i;      \
done
sed: can't read debian/fglrx.grub-gfxpayload.in: No such file or directory
# remove exec bit on everything
find arch \
    etc \
    lib \
    module \
    usr \
    xpic_64a     -type f | xargs chmod -x
find: 'module': No such file or directory
# set executable on user apps
find arch/x86_64/usr/sbin \
    arch/x86_64/usr/X11R6/bin \
    usr/sbin/ -type f | xargs chmod a+x
# set exec bit on scripts
find lib etc debian -name "*.sh" -type f | xargs chmod +x
# set the permissions on the pxpress scripts
chmod 744 debian/pxpress/switch*
dh build
make: dh: Command not found
debian/rules:98: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 127
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: 295: ./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: debclean: not found
dpkg-buildpackage: source package fglrx-installer
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 2:15.201-0ubuntu1
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution precise
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by AMD: Advanced Micro Devices. ati.amd.com/support/driver.html>
 dpkg-source --before-build fglrx.VaefHe
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
 debian/rules build
#Create important strings
for i in 10fglrx \
         control \
         dkms.conf \
         fglrx"".install \
         fglrx""-dev.install \
         fglrx""-dev.links \
         fglrx"".dirs \
         fglrx"".links \
         fglrx"".postinst \
         fglrx"".postrm \
         fglrx"".preinst \
         fglrx"".prerm \
         fglrx-amdcccle"".install \
         fglrx-amdcccle"".dirs \
         fglrx""-core.install \
         fglrx""-core.links \
         fglrx""-core.dirs \
         fglrx""-core.postinst \
         fglrx""-core.postrm \
         fglrx""-core.preinst \
         fglrx""-core.prerm \
         overrides/fglrx"" \
         overrides/fglrx""-dev \
         overrides/fglrx""-core \
         overrides/fglrx-amdcccle""; do \
    sed -e "s|#PKGXMODDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/xorg/modules|g" \
        -e "s|#LIBDIR#|usr/lib|g" \
        -e "s|#LIBDIR32#|usr/lib32|g" \
        -e "s|#BINDIR#|usr/bin|g" \
        -e "s|#SBINDIR#|usr/sbin|g" \
        -e "s|#SYSCONFDIR#|etc|g" \
        -e "s|#MANDIR#|usr/share/man/man1|g" \
        -e "s|#LDSOCONF#|usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf|g" \
        -e "s|#ALTLDSOCONF#|usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf|g" \
        -e "s|#ALTPRIORITY#|1000|g" \
        -e "s|#PXALTPRIORITY#|900|g" \
        -e "s|#AUTOSTARTDIR#|etc/xdg/autostart|g" \
        -e "s|#DATADIR#|usr/share|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGDESKDIR#|usr/share/fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGDATADIR#|usr/share/fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGCONFIGDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGBINDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/bin|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGLIBDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGLIBDIR32#|usr/lib32/fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGDRIVERSDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/xorg|g" \
        -e "s|#XORGEXTRA#|usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGEXTENSIONDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/xorg|g" \
        -e "s|#XORGEXTENSIONSDIR#|usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions|g" \
        -e "s|#DRIVERNAME#|fglrx""|g" \
        -e "s|#MODULENAME#|fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#DRIVERDIRNAME#|fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#DRIVERDEVNAME#|fglrx""-dev|g" \
        -e "s|#DRIVERSRCNAME#|fglrx-installer|g" \
        -e "s|#DRIVERCORENAME#|fglrx""-core|g" \
        -e "s|#FLAVOUR#|""|g" \
        -e "s|#DRIVERCTRLNAME#|fglrx-amdcccle""|g" \
        -e "s|#INCLUDEDIR#|usr/include|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGLIBCONFDIR#|lib/fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGXMODDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/xorg/modules|g" \
        -e "s|#PXDIR#|usr/lib/pxpress|g" \
        -e "s|#PXDIR32#|usr/lib32/pxpress|g" \
        -e "s|#PXXMODDIR#|usr/lib/pxpress/xorg/modules|g" \
        -e "s|#PXDIRNAME#|pxpress|g" \
        -e "s|#PXLIBDIR#|usr/lib/pxpress/lib|g" \
        -e "s|#PXLIBDIR32#|usr/lib32/pxpress/lib|g" \
        -e "s|#PXLDSOCONF#|usr/lib/pxpress/ld.so.conf|g" \
        -e "s|#ALTPXLDSOCONF#|usr/lib/pxpress/alt_ld.so.conf|g" \
        -e "s|#COREDIRNAME#|fglrx-core|g" \
        -e "s|#COREDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx-core|g" \
        -e "s|#COREDIR32#|usr/lib32/fglrx-core|g" \
        -e "s|#CORELDSOCONF#|usr/lib/fglrx-core/ld.so.conf|g" \
        -e "s|#COREPRIORITY#|1000|g" \
        -e "s|#UNBLKCOREPRIORITY#|900|g" \
        -e "s|#UNBLKCORELDSOCONF#|usr/lib/fglrx-core/unblacklist_ld.so.conf|g" \
        -e "s|#CVERSION#|15.201|g" \
        -e "s|#SRCXARCH#|xpic_64a|g" \
        -e "s|#SRCARCH#|x86_64|g" \
        -e "s|#SRCOTHERARCH#|x86|g" \
        -e "s|#SRCLIBDIR#|lib64|g" \
        -e "s|#DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH#|x86_64-linux-gnu|g" \
        -e "s|#OTHER_ARCH#|i386-linux-gnu|g" \
        debian/$i.in > debian/$i;      \
done
sed: can't read debian/fglrx-amdcccle.dirs.in: No such file or directory
# remove exec bit on everything
find arch \
    etc \
    lib \
    module \
    usr \
    xpic_64a     -type f | xargs chmod -x
find: 'module': No such file or directory
# set executable on user apps
find arch/x86_64/usr/sbin \
    arch/x86_64/usr/X11R6/bin \
    usr/sbin/ -type f | xargs chmod a+x
# set exec bit on scripts
find lib etc debian -name "*.sh" -type f | xargs chmod +x
# set the permissions on the pxpress scripts
chmod 744 debian/pxpress/switch*
dh build
make: dh: Command not found
debian/rules:241: recipe for target 'build-arch' failed
make: *** [build-arch] Error 127
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: 295: ./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: debclean: not found
dpkg-buildpackage: source package fglrx-installer
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 2:15.201-0ubuntu1
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution precise
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by AMD: Advanced Micro Devices. ati.amd.com/support/driver.html>
 dpkg-source --before-build fglrx.aDxNxh
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
 debian/rules build
#Create important strings
for i in 10fglrx \
         control \
         dkms.conf \
         fglrx"".install \
         fglrx""-dev.install \
         fglrx""-dev.links \
         fglrx"".dirs \
         fglrx"".links \
         fglrx"".postinst \
         fglrx"".postrm \
         fglrx"".preinst \
         fglrx"".prerm \
         fglrx-amdcccle"".install \
         fglrx-amdcccle"".dirs \
         fglrx""-core.install \
         fglrx""-core.links \
         fglrx""-core.dirs \
         fglrx""-core.postinst \
         fglrx""-core.postrm \
         fglrx""-core.preinst \
         fglrx""-core.prerm \
         overrides/fglrx"" \
         overrides/fglrx""-dev \
         overrides/fglrx""-core \
         overrides/fglrx-amdcccle""; do \
    sed -e "s|#PKGXMODDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/xorg/modules|g" \
        -e "s|#LIBDIR#|usr/lib|g" \
        -e "s|#LIBDIR32#|usr/lib32|g" \
        -e "s|#BINDIR#|usr/bin|g" \
        -e "s|#SBINDIR#|usr/sbin|g" \
        -e "s|#SYSCONFDIR#|etc|g" \
        -e "s|#MANDIR#|usr/share/man/man1|g" \
        -e "s|#LDSOCONF#|usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf|g" \
        -e "s|#ALTLDSOCONF#|usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf|g" \
        -e "s|#ALTPRIORITY#|1000|g" \
        -e "s|#PXALTPRIORITY#|900|g" \
        -e "s|#AUTOSTARTDIR#|etc/xdg/autostart|g" \
        -e "s|#DATADIR#|usr/share|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGDESKDIR#|usr/share/fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGDATADIR#|usr/share/fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGCONFIGDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGBINDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/bin|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGLIBDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGLIBDIR32#|usr/lib32/fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGDRIVERSDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/xorg|g" \
        -e "s|#XORGEXTRA#|usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGEXTENSIONDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/xorg|g" \
        -e "s|#XORGEXTENSIONSDIR#|usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions|g" \
        -e "s|#DRIVERNAME#|fglrx""|g" \
        -e "s|#MODULENAME#|fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#DRIVERDIRNAME#|fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#DRIVERDEVNAME#|fglrx""-dev|g" \
        -e "s|#DRIVERSRCNAME#|fglrx-installer|g" \
        -e "s|#DRIVERCORENAME#|fglrx""-core|g" \
        -e "s|#FLAVOUR#|""|g" \
        -e "s|#DRIVERCTRLNAME#|fglrx-amdcccle""|g" \
        -e "s|#INCLUDEDIR#|usr/include|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGLIBCONFDIR#|lib/fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGXMODDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/xorg/modules|g" \
        -e "s|#PXDIR#|usr/lib/pxpress|g" \
        -e "s|#PXDIR32#|usr/lib32/pxpress|g" \
        -e "s|#PXXMODDIR#|usr/lib/pxpress/xorg/modules|g" \
        -e "s|#PXDIRNAME#|pxpress|g" \
        -e "s|#PXLIBDIR#|usr/lib/pxpress/lib|g" \
        -e "s|#PXLIBDIR32#|usr/lib32/pxpress/lib|g" \
        -e "s|#PXLDSOCONF#|usr/lib/pxpress/ld.so.conf|g" \
        -e "s|#ALTPXLDSOCONF#|usr/lib/pxpress/alt_ld.so.conf|g" \
        -e "s|#COREDIRNAME#|fglrx-core|g" \
        -e "s|#COREDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx-core|g" \
        -e "s|#COREDIR32#|usr/lib32/fglrx-core|g" \
        -e "s|#CORELDSOCONF#|usr/lib/fglrx-core/ld.so.conf|g" \
        -e "s|#COREPRIORITY#|1000|g" \
        -e "s|#UNBLKCOREPRIORITY#|900|g" \
        -e "s|#UNBLKCORELDSOCONF#|usr/lib/fglrx-core/unblacklist_ld.so.conf|g" \
        -e "s|#CVERSION#|15.201|g" \
        -e "s|#SRCXARCH#|xpic_64a|g" \
        -e "s|#SRCARCH#|x86_64|g" \
        -e "s|#SRCOTHERARCH#|x86|g" \
        -e "s|#SRCLIBDIR#|lib64|g" \
        -e "s|#DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH#|x86_64-linux-gnu|g" \
        -e "s|#OTHER_ARCH#|i386-linux-gnu|g" \
        debian/$i.in > debian/$i;      \
done
sed: can't read debian/fglrx-amdcccle.dirs.in: No such file or directory
# remove exec bit on everything
find arch \
    etc \
    lib \
    module \
    usr \
    xpic_64a     -type f | xargs chmod -x
find: 'module': No such file or directory
# set executable on user apps
find arch/x86_64/usr/sbin \
    arch/x86_64/usr/X11R6/bin \
    usr/sbin/ -type f | xargs chmod a+x
# set exec bit on scripts
find lib etc debian -name "*.sh" -type f | xargs chmod +x
# set the permissions on the pxpress scripts
chmod 744 debian/pxpress/switch*
dh build
make: dh: Command not found
debian/rules:241: recipe for target 'build-arch' failed
make: *** [build-arch] Error 127
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
Removing temporary directory: fglrx-install.sdEDmD
```

Comment: Did you run with `sudo`?

Comment: No, but I think I'm already on root

Comment: unless you ran `su` or `sudo -i` before running the command, you didn't run it as root

Comment: this is the fglx-install log:

Supported adapter detected.
Check if system has the tools required for installation.
fglrx installation requires that the system have kernel headers.  /lib/modules/4.4.0-kali1-amd64/build/include/linux/version.h cannot be found on this system.
One or more tools required for installation cannot be found on the system. Install the required tools before installing the fglrx driver.
Optionally, run the installer with --force option to install without the tools.
Forcing install will disable AMD hardware acceleration and may make your system unstable. Not recommended.

Comment: OK. Open the Additional Drivers app and choose the `fglrx` option from there.

Comment: Where to find this app 'Additional Drivers'??

Comment: Search for it in the Dash.

Comment: I click on it but nothing shows off just blinks and nothing happens

Comment: what do you mean by that? It doesn't stay selected?

Comment: when I click on it, no window appears

Comment: Try running `software-properties-gtk --open-tab=4` in a terminal and see if it opens. If it gives an error, post it.

Comment: @WestWind, note `make: dh: Command not found` from the log. You need to install `debhelper` package. If you are going to install it this way by rebuilding Debian package, you gonna need more packages, long path.

Answer (score 2):

Are you by any chance running 16.04? If yes, the driver is deprecated as per release notes. The recommended solution will be to use the open source drivers (amdgpu and radeon)

```
Removed from disk on 2016-03-03.
Removal requested on 2016-03-03.
Deleted on 2016-03-03 by Martin Pitt

(tjaalton) there will not be updates any more, incompatible with new X.org ABI, free driver is good enough now
```

[Publishing history here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+publishinghistory)